# Un/Check All, Reset All Checkboxes using one master checkbox like in GMAIL

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am reading different car models from a database and place them in a form for a user to select one or more preferred car models using checkboxes. I am using the following code segements:

```
$("#checkAll").on("click", function () {

  var chk = document.getElementById('checkAll').checked;

  if (chk) {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i].name == 'check') arr[i].checked = true;
    }
  } else {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i].name == 'check') arr[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
});


 <form action="car_model.php" method="post" name="car_form" id="car_form">
   echo '<td class="caption" align="left" width="5%"><h2 class="table_heading">Select   car models</a><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll"></h2></td>';    
   $q10 = "SELECT ...
   $r10 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q10); 
   if (mysqli_num_rows($r10) > 0) {    
     while ($row10 = mysqli_fetch_array($r10, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
     {
       echo '<p class="normal_text"><input type="checkbox" name="model_selection[]" value="' . $row10['model_id'] . '" onclick="return KeepCount()"; />' . $row10['car_model_name'] . '</p></br>';      
     }
   }

 </form>
```

How do I allow a User to **Un/Check** All,reset All checkboxes Selection with a click of a button?

Comment: Has nothing to do with php.

Comment: You need to have a "listener" onClick on a button and then deselect all the others.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you can use the name attribute(`model_selection[]`) using [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to fetch all the checkbox elements and set its checked property to the checkAll elements(referred by `this` in the change handler) property.

It should be as simple as

```
$("#checkAll").on("change", function () {
    $('input[ name="model_selection[]"]').prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G7uze/)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery -

```
$("#checkAll").on("click", function () {
 var $input = $('input[name="model_selection[]"]');
 if(this.checked){
   $input.prop('checked',true);
 }else{
   $input.prop('checked',false);
 }
});
```